# Running cordova apps opens menu

Tags: android, cordova

I've noticed that every time I run a cordova app using `cordova run android`, it seems like the menu button is being pressed, the context menu on another currently open app pops up.

It doesn't bother me but I was just curious if anyone else has noticed this peculiar behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal. I can observe the same behaviour while developing on an android device.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me. But I'm still very curious as to _why_ this happens, I don't really call it 'normal' :-)